# Name the thing which increases and decreased at same time with same rate?

Tags: riddle

Name the thing which increases and decreased at same time with same rate?

i.e. If I'm distance I increase 1 meter and decrease 1 meter but i'm not distance

tell me who I'm?

Comment: I don't think it unclear, I would guess that the answer is rot13(lbhe yvsrfcna)

Comment: Orthogonal?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonality

Answer (score 4):

Here's something:

> The graph of $x = |y|$.

Here's how:

> [image]